# LDAPS installation issue on centos7

Tags: linux, ldap, centos7, openldap

I have installed ldaps on my cetos7 server and tried to give delegate access to a user while doing that I found that 'olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif' file is missing from the location /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn\=config and when I'm trying to restart slapd service I'm getting the following error `"**Job for slapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status slapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**"`

When I check slapd status I'm getting the following errors

```
 ***slapd.service - OpenLDAP Server Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-12-30 17:22:27 UTC; 7min ago
     Docs: man:slapd
           man:slapd-config
           man:slapd-hdb
           man:slapd-mdb
           file:///usr/share/doc/openldap-servers/guide.html
  Process: 26082 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h ${SLAPD_URLS} $SLAPD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 26068 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/openldap/check-config.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 21135 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)
 pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap by (uid=0)
check-config.sh[26068]: Checking configuration file failed:
 check-config.sh[26068]: 586697d3 ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif"
 check-config.sh[26068]: 586697d3 olcSuffix: value #0: <olcSuffix> namingContext "dc=blue,dc=com" already served by a preceding hdb database serving namingContext "dc=blue,dc=com"
 check-config.sh[26068]: 586697d3 config error processing olcDatabase={3}hdb,cn=config: <olcSuffix> namingContext "dc=blue,dc=com" already served by a preceding hdb database
 check-config.sh[26068]: slaptest: bad configuration file!
 systemd[1]: slapd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon.
 systemd[1]: Unit slapd.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: slapd.service failed.***
```

It would be very nice if someone could guide me through this.